# Unusual error with bytes calldata

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

interface tokenRecipient { 
function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes 
calldata _extraData) external; 
}

contract TokenERC20 {
// Public variables of the token
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals = 18;
// 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
uint256 public totalSupply;

// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constructor function
 *
 * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
 */
constructor(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string memory tokenName,
    string memory tokenSymbol
) public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
    name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

/**
 * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != address(0x0));
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address and notify
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
 */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, address(this), _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
 *
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens from other account
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
 *
 * @param _from the address of the sender
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the above code the 3rd line 
bytes calldata _extaData 
gives the following error:

```
browser/Coin.sol:4:92: ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier
function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes 
calldata  _extraData) external; 

          ^--------^
```

Please help me out with the error.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please accept it :) have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling your contract with Solidity compiler version `0.5.0` or higher.

The `calldata` keyword cannot be used like that in versions lower than `0.5.0`.

You are getting the `Expected ,` error because the pre-0.5.0 compiler thinks `calldata` is the name of the function parameter, instead of its memory location.